# Call function inside document.ready wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, document-ready

I want to be able to call a function from a link (this function will delete the corresponding row). If I place the function inside document ready it wont load upon call. But it works while outside. The function is delRow(id) located at the end of .

I tried making a 'copy' of  "$("#participants").click(function() {" and calling it just like the "Lägg till deltagare" link (add user link).

How do I solve this in the best way? And Why cant you call functions inside document.ready and why wont my copy of the participants click.function work? (I dont have it in the code example, i named it like "$("#deleterow").click(function() and set the id of the button to deleterow)

URL: http://min.xn--spyp-toa.se/addrows.php (Some DNS servers have problem with this, run googles DNS instead! 8.8.8.8 )

```
<?php 
//Inkluderar fil för inläsning av databasinfo.
require("core.inc");       
?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

         //Denna kod ska hämta users i databasen till js-arrayen users
           var users = new Array();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getuser.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(){alert("Kunde inte hämta data från databas");},
                success: function(data){
                    users = data;
                }
            });

        //Denna kod lägger till en ny rad
            var rowCount = 1; // Räknare som räknar hur många rader man lagt till
            var selectedUsers = new Array(); //Denna array innehåller användare man lagt till

            $("#participants").click(function() {

                var participantSelect = document.getElementById('participantSelect'); //Denna variabel håller värdet från selecten

                //En funktion som loopar fram användarna i databasen till <option> taggar
                function addOption(){

                    var option; //Denna variabel lagrar alla options som genereras i loopen

                    for (var i=0; i < users.length-1; i++)  {

                        var user = users[i].id;

                        if(jQuery.inArray(user, selectedUsers) > -1) {

                        }
                        else{
                           option += ('<option value="'+users[i].id+'">'+users[i].name+'</option>'); 
                        }
                    }
                    return option; //Skickar alla genererade <option>-taggar till append-scriptet
                }

                //Funktionen som uppdaterar <select>-satsen
                function updateSelect(){
                    $('#participantSelect').replaceWith('<select name="participantSelect" id="participantSelect">'+addOption()+'</select>');
                }

                //Function som matas in i apenden, den plockar ut namnet som hör till ID som kommer från selecten
                function name(){

                    //kör igenom arraeyn men avslutar när den hittar en träff
                    for(var i=0; users.length; i++){

                        if(users[i].id == participantSelect.value){ //Om användar ID är samma som ID från select

                            selectedUsers.push(users[i].id); //Denna lägger till valda användare i en array för filtrering av redan använda användare

                            //Denna funktion anropar koden som genererar om <select> och utelämnar redan valda användare
                            updateSelect();

                            return users[i].name; //Return i if-satsen för att avbryta vid träff.
                        } 
                    }
                }

                //Skriver in en input som är read-only med den valda användaren
                $('#container').append('<input type="text" name="participant_'+rowCount+'" id="'+participantSelect.value+'" value="'+name()+'" class="participant_1" readonly="readonly" /> <a href="#" name="participant_'+rowCount+'" id="'+rowCount+'" class="participant_1" onclick="bajs(this.name)">Ta bort deltagare</a><br>');

               rowCount++;                   
            });

            //Denna kod tar bort redan inmatad användare och lägger tillbaka denne i <select>
                function delRow(id){
                    alert(id);
                    alert("test");
                }
        });

    </script>

    <!-- Här väljer man vilka användare som deltagit, sedan trycker man på lägg till-knappen -->
    <select name="participantSelect" id="participantSelect">
                <?php

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM user");

                while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$db_field['id'].'">'.$db_field['name'].'</option>';
                }

                mysql_free_result($result);

              ?>
    </select>

    <!-- Knapp för att lägga till ny rad inom container-diven -->
    <a href="#" id="participants" class="myButton">L&auml;gg till deltagare</a>

    <!-- Container diven hit vad alla användare kommer läggas till-->
    <h2>Deltagare:</h2>
    <div id="container" class="container">
   <!-- Här kommer allt läggas in -->
    </div>  

    <button name="participant_1" id="delete_participants" onclick="delRow()">Ta bort deltagare</button><br>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use old-style DOM0 handler hookup (`onclick="..."`), any functions you reference in that string must be globals. Your `delRow` function isn't a global, it's contained by the function you're passing into `ready` — which is a good thing, the global namespace is already too full.

Two choices for dealing with this:

#### 1. Hook things up with jQuery

The best way (in my view) to deal with it is to hook up your `button` using jQuery from within your `ready` function. E.g.:

```
$("#delete_participants").click(delRow);
```

#### 2. Export just that function

Alternatively, you *could* make a global that points to `delRow` by doing this within the `ready` function:

```
window.delRow = delRow;
```

That works because all global variables are properties of the `window` object in browsers, so by assigning a reference to `delRow` to the `delRow` property on `window`, you're explicitly making it available in the global namespace (without cluttering up the global namespace with any of your other functions). Then the `onclick="..."` handler will be able to see it. But I wouldn't advocate using globals if you can avoid it. It's a useful bridging technique, though, as you transition from the old style to the newer style.

---

Side note: You don't *have* to use the `ready` function, you can just put your script at the bottom of the page (just before or after the ending `</body>` tag) and do this:

```
(function() {
    // Your code here
})();
```

It will run *slightly* sooner, and still have access to all of the DOM elements on the page ([ref](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) | [ref](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)). But `ready` is mostly fine too.

---

Re your comment below:

> I´ve given dynamic buttons the ID "delete_participants" and created the `$("#delete_participants").click(delRow);` but it aint getting called. It works for the static button tho.

That's because you can't have more than one element on a page with the same `id`. The `id` values **must** be unique.

If you're going to be adding and removing rows, and if you're using jQuery to hook things up, you have two additional choices:

#### A. Hook Them Up Individually

This is just a matter of calling `click(function() { ... })` on the new button once you've created it, e.g.:

```
var tr = '<tr><td><input type="button" name="delete"></td></tr>';
tr.find('input').click(delRow);
tr.appendTo(/* ...presumably a table body or something...*/);
```

So for instance, here's a complete example:

HTML:

```
<table id="participants">
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>
        <input type="button" name="add" value="Add Participant">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Joe Bloggs
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#participants")
    .delegate('input[name="add"]', "click", addParticipant)
    .delegate('input[name="delete"]', "click", delParticipant);

  function addParticipant() {
    var td, tr, name;

    // Obviously you'd use something more modern than `prompt`
    name = prompt("Name for new participant: ", "");
    if (name) {
      // And this code is no thing of beauty, either, but you get the idea
      td = $('<td>').text(name);
      tr = $('<tr>');
      tr.append(td);
      tr.append('<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>');
      tr.hide();
      $("#participants tbody").append(tr);
      tr.fadeIn();
      // Note we don't have to do anything to hook the new button;
      // delegation handles that
    }
  }

  function delParticipant() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(function() {
      tr.remove();
    });
  }

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/okuhec)

#### B. Use Event Delegation

But in cases like this, another technique is frequently better: Event delegation. In event delegation, you hook the event ("click") on some *container* of all of the things that might receive that click, and then when the click happens check to see if the event has passed through any of the relevant elements (because most events, including "click", "bubble" from the element on which the click actually occurred up to its parent, grandparent, and other ancestors). jQuery makes delegation dead easy, using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate):

```
$("selector_for_container").delegate("selector_for_element", "click", function() {
    // This will get called if the click matches the element selector
});
```

or, as of 1.7 or later, using one of the several variants of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$("selector_for_container").on("click", "selector_for_element", function() {
    // This will get called if the click matches the element selector
});
```

(Note that the order of arguments is slightly different.)

Complete example (using `delegate`, since a lot of people aren't on 1.7 yet):

HTML:

(Same as above)

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#participants")
    .delegate('input[name="add"]', "click", addParticipant)
    .delegate('input[name="delete"]', "click", delParticipant);

  function addParticipant() {
    var td, tr, name;

    // Obviously you'd use something more modern than `prompt`
    name = prompt("Name for new participant: ", "");
    if (name) {
      // And this code is no thing of beauty, either, but you get the idea
      td = $('<td>').text(name);
      tr = $('<tr>');
      tr.append(td);
      tr.append('<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>');
      tr.hide();
      $("#participants tbody").append(tr);
      tr.fadeIn();
      // Note we don't have to do anything to hook the new button;
      // delegation handles that
    }
  }

  function delParticipant() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(function() {
      tr.remove();
    });
  }

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/okuhec/2)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I updated the code at [link]http://min.spypå.se/addrows.php[/link] and I can now call the function from the "ta bort deltagare"-button at the bottom (now name "ta bort deltagare, test"). But I cant call it from buttons i dynamically add.

Comment: @DannyThunder: Just hook them up once you've added them, again using the relevant jQuery function (`click`, `bind`, or `on`) on a jQuery object containing the just-added button.

Comment: @T-j-crowder : I´ve given dynamic buttons the ID "delete_participants" and created the $("#delete_participants").click(delRow); but it aint getting called. It works for the static button tho. http://min.xn--spyp-toa.se/addrows.php

Comment: @DannyThunder: `id` values must be unique on the page: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute Also note that when you use `click` to hook up a button, the button must already exist.

Comment: @T-j-crowder : OK, thanks for the info! Guess I have to find another solution for the dynamically remove-buttons. Thats another question so I can mark this as solved! Thank you!

Comment: @DannyThunder: I've gone ahead and answered it here. See the update. Best,

Comment: @T-j-crowder: (is this the way to notice you?) Thanks alot for all the help! Worked like a charm! Have a virtual beer or kiss! Heck, have 'em both! :-D Will come back to this and vote up your answer as soon as I get enough rep.

Comment: @DannyThunder: LOL, thanks! (Since you're commenting on my answer, you don't have to do anything, I'll always get notified regardless of the `@` thing or not. When it matters, if you start with `@t` there should be an auto-completion pop-up.)

Answer (score 0):

"You've defined the function within a closure, so it's not accessible outside of that ready function"

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/call-functions-outside-document-ready

You should always put your functions outside the document ready closure for them to be accessible within the global scope.

Comment: Or better yet, avoid using global functions full stop.